# Why does this Roman numeral chord have a ♯ prefix?

Tags: chords, scales, chord-theory, roman-numerals

These are the chords for some A minor scales:

[image: Minor scales]

For melodic minor, why does the F♯<sup>o</sup> diminished chord have a '♯' in front of the Roman numeral, and the G♯<sup>o</sup> diminished chord does not?

Comment: In much music, the minor mode is treated as the union of these scales. The minor chord on step 5 is common though mostly as a key area. Often the v-i pattern will be used at non-final cadential points, reserving the V-i for the final cadence. The III+ is rare as is shown. The major IV sometimes occurs as it's used both for "color" and for giving a "modal" feel. Both ii and II (and II7) occur, especially at final cadences. My point is that all these need practice.

Answer (score 8):

When analyzing a piece in a minor key, the `VI` chord is presumed to be on the 6 native to that key (signature), while the `vii` is presumed to be raised. Since the 6 in melodic minor is raised, its triad requires a `#` to differentiate it and make clear it's the raised sixth. While `vii` is presumed raised, one sometimes sees `bVII` when appropriate, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

A sharp or flat precedes a Roman numeral if the chord root differs from the *key signature*.

That system is consistent except for chord roots of the seventh scale degree. Unfortunately, that is a mix of various assumptions.

If upper and lower case letters are being used, upper case `VII` is assumed to be a chord root on the *subtonic*, the scale degree one whole step below the tonic, and the chord quality will be a major triad. If the lower case `vii` is used, the chord root is assumed to be a leading tone one half step below the tonic, and the chord quality can either be assumed a diminished triad, or the `o` diminished symbol should ideally be given as `viio`.

While not part of your question, I dispute the "rare" label on the minor `v` and the augmented `III+`. Minor `v` is actually common. `III+` is also fairly common, but you might be able to analyze that chord as some kind of non-chord tone action involving a dominant chord. Ex. root `E` with a `G♯` and above a `C` moving down to `B`. `E G♯ C` being an augmented chord, which has some ambiguity regarding the root, or it's a dominant chord `E G♯` with `C` and appoggiatura resolving down to `B`.

What the charts in your example do not show, but are probably more common uses of sharp and flat prefixes to Roman numerals are the *neapolitan* chord, which could be labelled as `♭II` and borrowed chords. For example, in `C` major the submediant triad is labelled  `C:vi`, but borrowed from the minor the submediant will be labelled `C:♭VI`.